# Spring config file naming convention

Tags: spring

What actually is the naming convention in Spring that the config file has to have a name "servletname-.xml".
 If the name is different, will it not work?

How does this reconcile with the fact that we can have a name : spring-config.xml and load it with new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml"). There seems to be no need to follow a naming convention here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention is just that: a convention. It is defined in the [FrameworkServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html) on which the (popular) [DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) is built. You can change the location by setting the *contextConfigLocation* param.